# Retrieve network camera stream URL in Linux

Tags: c, linux, onvif

I am trying to retrieve rtsp URLs of cameras on my network. I can do this using Onvif Device Manager on Windows but how to do this on Linux using C/C++ or command line tool. I have tried various libs e.g. [onvifc](https://github.com/xsmart/onvifc) (OpenCVR) and [onvifcpplib](https://github.com/xsmart/onvifcpplib) but none of them could compile on Linux, neither they have API documentation. Any suggestions please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a gsoap-onvif solution from https://github.com/tonyhu/gsoap-onvif. This programs successfully retrieves parameters from most of the Onvif complaint cameras.

Comment: The project you suggested has compilation problems, at least for my linux distro. Better use this fork: https://github.com/paullouisageneau/gsoap-onvif

Answer (score 0):

you can have a try with python onvif, some feature you can use, may be other feature such as PTZ you can use .

also, you can have a try with opencvr's another project, https://github.com/veyesys/h5stream, if you can't compile,you can download from sourceforge.

Good luck.

Comment: I've tried python onvif, and for some reason it's not working (it crashes my IP camera). :S